# Consolidate single multi-dimensional array by individual key of nested array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

The question makes this sound way more complicated than it is. I have poured too much time into trying every variation of array_merge, etc. Maybe this is easy for someone:

I have a multi-dimensional array:

```
$array = [
        0 => [
            'class' => 'A',
            'jon' => '0.50'
        ],
        1 => [
            'class' => 'B',
            'jon' => '0.40'
        ],
        2 => [
            'class' => 'A',
            'steve' => '0.90'
        ],
        3 => [
            'class' => 'B',
            'steve' => '0.80'
        ]
    ];
```

The keys (0,1,2,3) aren't important. I want to consolidate this array based on the `class` key within each nested array. Desired outcome:

```
$outcome = [
        0 => [
            'class' => 'A',
            'jon' => '0.50',
            'steve' => '0.90'
        ],
        1 => [
            'class' => 'B',
            'jon' => '0.40',
            'steve' => '0.80'
        ]
    ];
```

Working in PHP7.4 if relevant, but I doubt it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Write a cycle where you will build an array with keys of your class and if the key does not exist, create a value under it, if the key exists, merge the value with the previous one. If you don't want to have class as a key, call `array_values` after your loop.

Comment: Thanks, Denis. Why the down votes? Any additional detail I can? Apologies if array transformations aren't the most sexy topic.

Comment: I didn't downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would probably work.

```
$sorted = [];
foreach ($array as $item) {
    $sorted[$item['class']] = array_merge($item, $sorted[$item['class']] ?? []);
}
```

- Iterating each item and plucking out the `class` property to make the key of the array
- We then either merge the elements already attached to that key with the current item or thanks to the null coalescing operator - use an empty array